# C++: Instantiate many templates in library

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a library with a class templated on a size:

`foo.hpp`:

```
template <size_t N>
struct Foo {
   void bar();
};
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
template <size_t N>
void Foo<N>::bar() {
...
};
```

I want the compiled version to be instatiated for a specific list of sizes which would be defined in the cpp file. In pseudocode, something like this

`foo.cpp`:

```
template <size_t N>
void Foo<N>::bar() {
...
};

for (const auto & size: {1,2,7,9})
    template struct Foo<size>;
```

Right now, I am manually doing this (instatiating for each type), but this is error prone since I have several files that should be defined for the same size.

I am aware that I could move everything to the header file, and use some `enable_if`'s to choose which sizes are valid. However, I want to hide the implementation details. Hence the current approach.

EDIT:

FWIW, I was hoping to avoid macros. I thought that something like this would work if you want a range of variables (e.g. 1,2,3,4...):

```
template<template<size_t> class E, size_t I = 1, std::enable_if_t<I >= 5> *unused = nullptr>
bool instatiator() {
  return true;
}

template<template<size_t> class E, size_t I = 1, std::enable_if_t<I < 5> *unused = nullptr>
bool instatiator() {
  E<I> e;
  return instatiator<E, I + 1>();
}

bool unused = instatiator<Encoder>();
```

but I can't seem to get that working.

Comment: Don't you still need validation in the header file so that a user won't pick a size for which there's no instantiation in the implementation file?

Comment: No. I am fine with them seeing a linking error. This is the behavior I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) approach for this:

**valid_sizes.hpp**

```
// Note: no include guards!!

PROCESS_SIZE(1)
PROCESS_SIZE(2)
PROCESS_SIZE(7)
PROCESS_SIZE(9)

#undef PROCESS_SIZE
```

**foo.cpp**

```
// ...

#define PROCESS_SIZE(n) template struct Foo<n>;
#include "valid_sizes.hpp"
```

**bar.cpp**

```
// ...

#define PROCESS_SIZE(n) some_other_use_of<n>;
#include "valid_sizes.hpp"
```

---

Alternatively, instead of a manual list, you could use Boost.Preprocessor:

**process_sizes.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#define PROCESS_SIZES(macro, data) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(macro, data, (1)(2)(7)(9))
```

**some header file**

```
#define INSTANTIATE_CLASS(r, Name, size) template class Name<size>;
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "process_sizes.hpp"

// ...

PROCESS_SIZES(INSTANTIATE_CLASS, Foo)
```

**bar.cpp**

```
#include "process_sizes.hpp"

// ...

PROCESS_SIZES(INSTANTIATE_CLASS, Bar)

#define OTHER_SIZE_BASED_WORK(r, data, size) other_use_of<size>;
PROCESS_SIZES(OTHER_SIZE_BASED_WORK, whatever)
```

---

Note that explicit instantiation definitions must occur at namespace scope, so it's not possible put them inside a function like your attempted `instantiator`.

And also note that an implicit instantiation (such as would be caused by referring to the class in a context which requires it to be defined) is not "visible" outside the translation unit, so it cannot be used as a substitute for explicit instantiation.

In other words, having the same list of sizes do different things requires duplicating the list for each use, using macros, or using custom code generation outside of the C++ compilation pipeline. I consider macros the simplest and most maintainable of these.

Comment: I knew there would be a macro way of doing this. I really hate using macros though (perhaps unfairly). Let's see if there is an alternative.

Comment: This is a valid use of macros IMHO, because what you're trying to do is use some meta-language to generate C++ code ... and that's what the preprocessor is good for.

Comment: @bremen_matt I agree with Jonathan here. Until we get metaclasses in C++, this is *the* job for macros.

Comment: If you don't want macro, just copy&paste the specific lines a few times. Seems KISS to me. "void Foo<1>::bar() { /*Just call some actual impl here*/ }; template struct Foo<1>;"

Comment: @OneManMonkeySquad The thing is that the OP wants *one list of sizes* used for several purposes. The quesiton is how not to duplicate this list's definition.

Comment: Right. There are several structs in different translation units that should be instantiated like this. I want a single place to do that

Comment: Well, then you have to use macros and/or code gen. Magic is not free.

Comment: I thought the template approach that I laid out would work. I just could not figure that out.

Comment: That approach doesn't work because the `E<I> e;` variable is unused, so can be optimized away, and so the template instantiations are not emitted by the compiler (at least when optimising). You really need an explicit instantiation definition to ensure the compiler actually generates the code you're it asking for.

Comment: @JonathanWakely And even if it was emitted, it wouldn't be (reliably) accessible from clients using the library which contains it, right?

Comment: I think the template way forward would be to instantiate a struct that has a separate field for each class size. You should be able to do that by making one large tuple type. I need more time to figure that out though

Comment: @bremen_matt - That won't work either. An implicit instantiation of a class template will not instantiate its member functions (templates), only their declarations. You'd have to use the member function (template). That quickly stops being advantageous. You need the explicit instantiation here, and you can only get it with a macro. There is no other standard solution besides some use of the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Angew answer:
xmacros can be in a different manner, allowing include guards and also avoiding having `#include` in the middle of the code:

valid_sizes.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

#define SIZES_TABLE(OP)\
OP(1) \
OP(2) \
OP(12)
```

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include "valid_sizes.hpp"
// ...
#define INSTANTIATE(Size) template struct Foo<Size>;
SIZES_TABLE(INSTANTIATE)
#undef INSTANTIATE
```

Comment: I fail to see the relevance. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @StoryTeller It is just another way of creating xmacro, which avoid having includes in the middle of the code

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively instantiate the `Foo` class with a helper class. Unfortunately you need to provide a call to each method of `Foo` in the constructor (the methods will not be called though), in order to provide the definitions to the linker:

```
// foo.cpp: 

template <size_t S>
struct recursive_helper {
  Foo<S> foo;
  recursive_helper<S-1> r_helper;

  recursive_helper() {
    foo.bar();
    foo.baz();
  }
};

template <>
struct recursive_helper<0> {
  Foo<0> foo;
  recursive_helper() {
    foo.bar();
    foo.baz();
  };
};
```

And then you instantiate the helper class:
`template struct recursive_helper<6>;`

Comment: This doesn't seem to link: https://wandbox.org/permlink/fAMPeWfepQsPssFy

Comment: Thats because `foo.cpp` was not included in the compile command: [https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wp0UfFBLztmzsCbL](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Wp0UfFBLztmzsCbL)